# Using getElementsByTagName works with H4 and TR tags – but not with DIV tag?

Tags: javascript, var, getelementsbytagname

With a list of football results from several seasons, I'm using checkboxes to let users filter entries in a table dynamically populated by a MySQL query.

To do this, I'm using the following script:

```
function updateDisplay() {
    var s1Display = "";
    if (!document.getElementById("8081").checked) {
        s1Display = "none";
    }
(...)
    var s13Display = "";
    if (!document.getElementById("9293").checked) {
        s13Display = "none";
    }

    var possibleEntries = document.getElementsByTagName("h4");
    for (var i = 0; i < possibleEntries.length; i++) {
         if (possibleEntries[i].getAttribute("class").indexOf("1980-1") == 0) {
             possibleEntries[i].style.display = s1Display;
        } 
(...) 
    else if (possibleEntries[i].getAttribute("class").indexOf("1992-3") == 0) {
             possibleEntries[i].style.display = s13Display ;
        }  
    }
}
```

I'm also using the following PHP code, with the various elements populated by the query involved:

```
echo "<h4 class='".$compShortCode." result-date'>".$yearonly."</h4>";
echo "<div class='".$compShortCode." result-info'>";
    echo "<a href='/seasons/match/MATCHID/' class='result-data result-link'>";
    echo "<span class='result-column sidebar-comp'>COMP</span>";    
    echo "<span class='result-column sidebar-venue'>VENUE</span>";
    echo "<span class='result-column sidebar-team'>TEAM</span>";
    echo "<span class='result-column sidebar-score'>";
        echo "<span class='player-score-box'>";
            echo "<span class='player-score-main'>SCORE</span>";
        echo "</span>";
    echo "</span>"; 
echo "</a>";
echo "</div>";
```

When a tickbox is checked, it shows the entry. When it's unchecked, it's designed to hide the entry. The way the code is currently configured, `document.getElementsByTagName("h4")` shows/hides the `<H4>` tag using `$compShortCode` – but switching to `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` won't do this. And I can't figure out why.

The error message in Chrome's Developer Tools is not making it clearer for me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
    at updateDisplay ((index):421)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange ((index):447)
```

I'm aiming to adapt the script so that it hides both the `<h4>` and `<div>` as the `$compShortCode` will be the same for both (using `document.querySelectorAll('div,h4')`?) – but first I'm looking to figure out why the `<div>` tag won't show/hide. I thought it was a straight swap from one tag to another or have I missed out a step?

For more context, the live page can be found [here](https://www.boroguide.co.uk/missing/).

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName()` is not broken.

Comment: Well, look at what comes before `indexOf` in your code: `getAttribute("class")`. That is what is returning null, not `getElementsByTagName`. So you likely have a `div` somewhere in your document that does not have a class attribute.

Comment: A better way to test if it has a class is `possibleEntries[i].classList.contains("1980-1")`